# How can I plot 4000 images line by line in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to plot 4000 images line by line as a subplot or with another method. When I use subplot method, the displayed image size is decreasing in some way. I would like to fix that and understand what causes decreasing in plotting size, or learn the other ways to plot images.

```
for ix in range(0, len(preds_train_t)):
    fig = plt.figure()
    #ix = random.randint(0, len(preds_train_t))
    fig.add_subplot(ix+1, 3, 1) 
    plt.imshow(np.dstack((X_train[ix],X_train[ix],X_train[ix])))   

    tmp = np.squeeze(Y_train[ix]).astype(np.float32)
    fig.add_subplot(ix+1, 3, 2) 
    plt.imshow(np.dstack((tmp,tmp,tmp)))

    tmp = np.squeeze(preds_train_t[ix]).astype(np.float32)
    fig.add_subplot(ix+1, 3, 3) 
    plt.imshow(np.dstack((tmp,tmp,tmp)))
    plt.show()
```

results of Jupyter notebook:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ix in range(0, len(preds_train_t)):
        fig = plt.figure()
        #ix = random.randint(0, len(preds_train_t))
        fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1) 
        plt.imshow(np.dstack((X_train[ix],X_train[ix],X_train[ix])))   

        tmp = np.squeeze(Y_train[ix]).astype(np.float32)
        fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2) 
        plt.imshow(np.dstack((tmp,tmp,tmp)))

        tmp = np.squeeze(preds_train_t[ix]).astype(np.float32)
        fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3) 
        plt.imshow(np.dstack((tmp,tmp,tmp)))
        plt.show()
```

I have changed the "ix+1" to "1" and problem has been solved as for loop causes new line in jupyter notebook for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for faster and more efficient way of plotting images in notebooks you should consider using [ipyplot](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot)

```py
import ipyplot

ipyplot.plot_images(X_train, img_width=150)
```

[image]